# How to get javascript generated html that I see by clicking "inspect element" in browser?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the hours of the available time slots from this webpage (the boxes below the calendar):

https://magicescape.it/le-stanze/lo-studio-di-harry-houdini/

I've read other related questions and wrote this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://magicescape.it/le-stanze/lo-studio-di-harry-houdini/'
wait_time = 10
options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time)
first_result = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "sb_main")))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(soup)

driver.quit()
```

After switching to the iframe containing the time slots, I get this from printing `soup`

```
<script id="time_slots_view" type="text/html"><div class="slots-view{{#ifCond (getThemeOption 'timeline_modern_display') '==' 'as_table'}} as-table{{/ifCond}}">
    <div class="timeline-wrapper">
        <div class="tab-pd">
            <div class="container-caption">
                {{_t 'available_services_on_this_day'}}
            </div>

            {{#if error_message}}
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                    {{error_message}}
                </div>
            {{/if}}

            {{>emptyTimePart is_empty=is_empty is_loaded=is_loaded}}

            <div id="sb_time_slots_container"></div>
            {{> bookingTimeLegendPart legend="only_available" time_diff=0}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div></script>
<script id="time_slot_view" type="text/html"><div class="slot">
    <a class="sb-cell free {{#ifPluginActive 'slots_count'}}{{#if available_slots}}has-available-slot{{/if}}{{/ifPluginActive}}" href="#{{bookingStepUrl time=time date=date}}">
        {{formatDateTime datetime 'time' time_diff}}

        {{#ifCond (getThemeOption 'timeline_show_end_time') '==' 1}}
            -<span class="end-time">
                &nbsp;{{formatDateTime end_datetime 'time' time_diff}}
            </span>
        {{/ifCond}}

        {{#ifPluginActive 'slots_count'}}
            {{#if available_slots}}
                <span class="slot--available-slot">
                    {{available_slots}}
                    {{#ifConfigParam 'slots_count_show_total' '==' true}} / {{total_slots}} {{/ifConfigParam}}
                </span>
            {{/if}}
        {{/ifPluginActive}}
    </a>
</div></script>
```

while from right click > inspect element in the webpage I get this

```
<div class="slots-view">
  <div class="timeline-wrapper">
    <div class="tab-pd">
      <div class="container-caption">
        Orari d'inizio disponibili
      </div>
      <div id="sb_time_slots_container">
        <div class="slot">
          <a class="sb-cell free " href="#book/location/4/service/6/count/1/provider/6/date/2020-03-09/time/23:00:00/">
            23:00
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="time-legend">
        <div class="available">
          <div class="circle">
          </div>
          - Disponibile
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the hour of the available slots (23:00 in this example) using selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired response you need to:

1. Correctly identify the `iframe` you want to switch to (and switch to it). You were trying to switch to `frame[0]` but needed `frame[1]`. The following code removes reliance on indexes and uses `xpath` instead.
2. Get the elements containing the time. Again this uses `xpath` to identify all child `div`'s of an element with `id=sb_time_slots_container`.
3. We then iterate over these child `div`'s and get the text property, which is nested within an `<a>` of these `div`'s.

For both steps 1 & 2 you should also use `wait.until` so that the content can be loaded.

```
...
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time)

# Wait until the iframe exists then switch to it
iframe_element = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="prenota"]//iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)

# Wait until the times exist then get an array of them
wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sb_time_slots_container"]/div')))
all_time_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sb_time_slots_container"]/div')

# Iterate over each element and print the time out
for elem in all_time_elems:
    print(elem.find_element_by_tag_name("a").text)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: And this gets around the fact it's all pulled as scripts?

Comment: Yes, the script is injecting html into the rendered page. The `wait.until`'s ensure that the content has loaded before trying to read it. You could add a try/catch for `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`, to handle cases where the content wasn't found in the specified time (which is 10secs in the OPs code).

Comment: Thanks. I assume this isn't possible just using requests?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! What if there was more than a single `<a>` inside a `<div>` instead?

Comment: @Alistair, no the waits are crucial. If you're only getting a single element, the `wait.until` can return it. If you're getting an array of elements you'll need to use `wait.until` then `find_elements_by...`. Example usages in the above code are getting the frame(single) vs getting the time divs(multiple)

Comment: @release_the_gil The parent is identified with `id="sb_time_slots_container"`. Children of that are `<div><a>hh:mm</a></div><div><a>hh:mm</a></div>`, which is why we iterate over the `<div>`'s, not the `<a>`'s. If there were multiple `<a>`'s within each time `<div>` you would change the for-loop to get a specific `<a>` or add a nested loop to iterate over all `<a>`'s depending on how the html structure changed